# How can validate condition in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having issue trying to create a validate condition to not allow to save records if it exists.

table open_courses

```
|id|   |name|
  1     Course 1
  2     Course 2
```

table movers

```
|id|  |name|
  1  mover 1
  2  Mover 2
```

table open_course_deails

```
|id| |open_course_id|  |mover_id
  1        1                1    #correct save
  2        2                1    #correct save
  3        1                2    #correct save
  4        2                2    #correct save
  5        1                1    #should not save the information
  6        1                2    #should not save the information
  7        2                1    #should not save the information
  8        2                2    #should not save the information
```

Here is the controller.

```
def new
  @open_course_detail= OpenCourseDetail.new
end

def create
  @open_course_detail.new(open_course_params)
  if @open_course.save
    redirect_to :index
  end
end
```

Here is the view.

```
<%= form_for @open_course_detail do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :open_course_id  %>
  <%= f.text_field :mover_id  %>  
<$ end %>
```

Here is the model open_course_detail.rb

```
validates :open_course_id,:uniqueness => { message => "Already in use" }
```

Also I tried:

```
 validates :mover_id,:uniqueness => { message => "Already in use" }
```

Comment: What is the actual heuristic for which records are valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got it correctly you can't have more than one pair for a row. Try `scope`

```
validates :open_course_id, :uniqueness => { :message => "Already in use", :scope => :mover_id }
```

or the other way around, it's up to you.

Comment: Let me know! :)

Answer (score 0):

Custom validation -

```
  class OpenCourseDeails < ApplicationRecord

      validate :record_present

      def record_present
        records = OpenCourseDeails.where("open_course_id = ? AND mover_id = ?", self.open_course_id, self.mover_id)
        if records.present?
          errors.add(:record, "Already present!")
        end
      end

  end
```